# How to lock a snapshot in VMware?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

We have created a VM and took a snapshot.

Then we made changes in that VM and made it as domain controller. That state also saved in snapshot.

Now i want to lock the snapshot. My intention is that i should not deleted that snapshot by mistake.

Is it possible to lock the snapshot? Or if i delete all snapshots, will it be merged with base VM?

Answer (score 3):

Those snapshots are useless. If you ever try to revert a domain controller VM to an older snapshot, it will wreak havoc on the rest of the Active Directory.

That said, there is no way (at least that I am aware of) to "lock" a snapshot so that nobody can delete it.

Comment: Active Directory never did support rollbacks in this manner -more details @ http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888794. Sync goes all over the place and AD becomes a tombstoned if you use snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use the DCUI and change the permissions of the snap file but really **DON'T** do this, it would be deeply stupid.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answers, snapshots should not be used long-term.  They are ideal for testing changes over the short term (hours, days, maybe weeks).  But keeping snapshots long term impacts VM performance, and can even fill up a datastore with delta files.

Snapshots != backups.